# Does Qt provide an interactive guide solution?

Tags: qt, user-interface

Are there any classes within the Qt API that provides some form of interactive guide? An interactive help of sorts. It's become the norm in web UX, but wanted to know if Qt provided anything out of the box for this.

Here's some examples of what I mean.

https://www.userlane.com/

http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/

Comment: nop............

Comment: it's unclear if you want help about developing with Qt (there is a lot, but unstructured), or a prebuilt 'wizard helper'. In last case, see [this sample](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-classwizard-example.html)

Comment: A QWizard/QWizardPage are classes meant to walk you through a process with a series of windows. An interactive on-screen guide highlights the UI itself and acts as tutorial, demonstrating how to use the GUI in question. As far as I'm concerned, these are not the same thing. Was just wondering if I missed an outofthebox class that does the latter in Qt.